# RoR mySQL Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `Netbeans 6.5` and started a Rails project but getting the error below but I already have mySQL install. Running Windows XP.

> LoadError in TestController#index
>
> 126: The specified module could not be found.   -
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7.3-x86-mswin32/ext/mysql.so
>
> RAILS_ROOT: C:/Temp/RailsApplication1 Application Trace | Framework
>   Trace | Full Trace
>
> c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7.3-x86-mswin32/ext/mysql.so
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:7:in
>   `require_library_or_gem'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in`
>   silence_warnings'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:5:in
>   `require_library_or_gem'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:63:in`
>   mysql_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in
>   `send'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in`
>   new_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in
>   `checkout_new_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in`
>   checkout'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in
>   `loop'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in`
>   checkout' c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in`
>   checkout'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in
>   `connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in`
>   retrieve_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:121:in
>   `retrieve_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:113:in`
>   connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in
>   `cache'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:12:in`
>   perform_action'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in
>   `send'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in`
>   process_without_filters'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in
>   `process_without_session_management_support'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:134:in`
>   process'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:392:in
>   `process'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:183:in`
>   handle_request'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in
>   `dispatch_unlocked'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in`
>   dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in
>   `synchronize'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in`
>   dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in
>   `dispatch_cgi'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in`
>   dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:103:in
>   `handle_dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:74:in`
>   service' c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in`run'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in`start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in`start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:60:in
>   `dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:66
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   gem_original_require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:49
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `gem_original_require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   require' script/server:3
>
> c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7.3-x86-mswin32/ext/mysql.so
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:7:in
>   `require_library_or_gem'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in`
>   silence_warnings'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:5:in
>   `require_library_or_gem'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:63:in`
>   mysql_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in
>   `send'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in`
>   new_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in
>   `checkout_new_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in`
>   checkout'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in
>   `loop'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in`
>   checkout' c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in`
>   checkout'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in
>   `connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in`
>   retrieve_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:121:in
>   `retrieve_connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:113:in`
>   connection'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in
>   `cache'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:12:in`
>   perform_action'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in
>   `send'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in`
>   process_without_filters'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in
>   `process_without_session_management_support'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:134:in`
>   process'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:392:in
>   `process'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:183:in`
>   handle_request'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in
>   `dispatch_unlocked'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in`
>   dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in
>   `synchronize'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in`
>   dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in
>   `dispatch_cgi'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in`
>   dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:103:in
>   `handle_dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:74:in`
>   service' c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in`run'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in`start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in`start'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:60:in
>   `dispatch'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:66
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   gem_original_require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:49
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `gem_original_require'
>   c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   require' script/server:3

This error occurred while loading the following files:

> mysql
>
> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> None
>
> Show session dump
>
> ---  flash: !map:ActionController::Flash::FlashHash {}
>
> Response
>
> Headers:
>
> {"cookie"=>[],  "Content-Type"=>"",  "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}

Please advise.

**Update:**

I tried installing mySQL again, getting:

> Successfully installed mysql-2.7.3-x86-mswin32 1 gem installed
>   Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.7.3-x86-mswin32... Installing
>   RDoc documentation for mysql-2.7.3-x86-mswin32... ERROR:  While
>   generating documentation for mysql-2.7.3-x86-mswin32 ... MESSAGE:
>   Unhandled special: Special: type=17, text="" ... RDOC args: --op c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/mysql-2.7.3-x86-mswin32/rdoc -
>   -exclude ext --main README --quiet ext README docs/README.html (continuing with the rest of the installation)

Then the same mySQL error when my app starts.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like you are missing the mysql gem.

Try

```
gem install mysql
```